# I want to call an executable from nant script but the nant should not wait for the executable's completion

Tags: svn, nant

I want to do svn commit in nant script but commit is taking hours together. I don't want nant to wait for wait such a long, instead, nant to call a batch file or svn and exit immediately -- and the svn/executable/batch should continue to do its operation.

Any suggestions would be more helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.. If you call a .bat file from NAnt, with would just trigger it and move onto the other NAnt commands. It will not wait for it to complete unless you specify the `wait` command.

- Generate your svn commit command into a svn.commit.bat file
- call that batch file within NAnt  `<exec program="svn.commit.bat" />`

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of the EXEC task ([EXEC](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/exec.html)), SPAWN attribute (Set it to TRUE). This will spin off a new process and will not wait for it to finish.

> spawn - Gets or sets a value indicating whether the application should
>   be spawned. If you spawn an application, its output will not be logged
>   by NAnt. The default is false.